# what is execution order of TestNG?

Tags: java, xml, selenium, testng

Parent class has @BeforeClass. Child class has @BeforeClass and @Test. What is an execution order?
What is execution order if @BeforeClass methods’ names in both classes are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `@BeforeClass` in parent class is executed, then `@BeforeClass` in child class.
If `@BeforeClass` name is the same in parent and child class, then you are just overriding the method so only child class `@BeforeClass` is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the order of the annotations, I quote from [TestNG documentation](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html):
*"TestNG guarantees that the "@Before" methods are executed in inheritance order (highest superclass first, then going down the inheritance chain), and the "@After" methods in reverse order (going up the inheritance chain)"*

Here's an example.
In this example,
The Before running order is: A_BeforeClass -> B_BeforeClass
The After running order is: B_AfterClass -> A_AfterClass

```
   public class A {
     @BeforeClass
      A_BeforeClass(){...}
       
     @AfterClass
       A_AfterClass(){...}       
    }
    
    public class B extends A {    
     @BeforeClass
       public void B_BeforeClass(){...}

     @AfterClass
       public void B_AfterClass(){...}
    }
```

Now, if we change the name of B_BeforeClass() to A_Beforeclass(), the method is overridden, therefore, only A_BeforeClass implemented in class B will be executed.

However, inheritance from a non-abstract class and override the parent test fixture **is not a good code practise**. It makes the tests harder to understand and increases code maintenance effort.

I would suggest trying to **avoid inheritance from non-abstract test cases**. If the two test cases share many test methods, a better solution would be to either create a test utility class or refactor the common test methods to a separate test case.